# what is the fastest way to 'zip' a binary stream?

Tags: actionscript-3

suggest there are binary stream contains 8 bytes

i want to get a new stream that contains this:

take every first bit of each bite to form the first byte

take every second bit of each bite to form the second byte

....

take every 8th bit of each bite to form the last byte

just like a zip() in python but in a binary form.

here's my code

```
        //create example data
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        for(var i:int=0;i<8;i++){
            ba.writeByte(Math.random()*256);
        }
        ba.position = 0;

        //process 8 bytes
        var eightbytes:Array = new Array();
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            eightbytes.push(ba.readByte());
        }
        var j:int = 128;
        var ba2:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            var result:int = 0;
            for(var k:int = 0;k<8;k++){
                var byte:int = eightbytes[k]&j;
                if(i<k){
                    byte = byte>>(k-i);
                }else if(i>k){
                    byte = byte<<(i-k);
                }
                result=result||byte;
            }
            ba2.writeByte(result);
            j=j>>1;
        }

        trace(ba);
        trace(ba2);
```

this is not good at dealing with large amount of data.i have to read and write bytes one by one, and do a 8x8 loops for every 8-bytes block.is there a way i can fasten it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out workers, they are the closest thing to threads in as3. They would do parallel calculations and after you wait for all 8 to finish you combine your result. It will also stop interface locking because of calculations.

Comment: Worth noting that, as of AIR 3.8, workers are still not supported on mobile. The asker doesn't specifically mention mobile, but it is always worth including given how prominent AIR mobile development is in the Flash world.